# Error: [2024-02-11T11:05:28.743Z] @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.7.2): FIRESTORE (10.7.2) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I get this error:

> [2024-02-11T11:05:28.743Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.7.2): FIRESTORE (10.7.2) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state while writing to firestore.

How do i fix it?

Here is my code for the signup onPress handler. Note that resetForm and setSubmitting are functions from yup library used for form validation.

```
const { SignUpAuth } = useContext(AuthContext)

const handleSignUp = async (values, {resetForm, setSubmitting}) => {
  delete values.confirmPassword
  console.log("values: ", values)
  
  try {
      setSubmitting()
      const onSuccess = await SignUpAuth(values)
      onSuccess && resetForm()
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error signing up:', error.message);
  }
};
```

AuthContext

```
export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => { 
  const [onSuccess, setOnSuccess] = useState(false)

  const SignUpAuth = async (user) => {
      
      try {
          const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, user.email, user.password);
          const uid = userCredential.user.uid;
          const newUser = await setDoc(doc(collection(db, "Community"), uid), {
              username: user.username,
              email: user.email,
              FirstName: '',
              LastName: '',
              walletBalance: 0,
              startTimer: 0,
              endTimer: 0,
              RegDate: new Date(),
              invitee: user.referrer,
              KYC: false,
              position: 0
          } )
          setOnSuccess(true)
          console.log(`user signed up ${newUser.username} successfully`)
          return true
      } catch (error) {
          console.error(error)
          return false
      } 
  }

  // const SignInAuth = async => {
      
  // }
  return(
  <AuthContext.Provider value={{SignUpAuth, isLogedIn, onSuccess }}>
      {children}
  </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

I tried changing my firestore rule from this

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2024, 2, 24);
    }
  }
}
```

to this

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

but it still gave same error
createUserWithEmailAndPassword works fine but i can't add the fields to the firestore.
Also, in firestore console, the community collection is exists but the document doesn't, so i am using setDoc to create it if it doesn't